# autocomplete for textarea and other functions

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Though what I would like to do is get rid of the availableTags and make it so it searches within say div.post h3.username  And from there get the users names. Also I want to use this for a textarea is this possible?

Next question is is it possible to make this only work when you first write @ then the users like @T will show up all the T users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have every username you'd like to use in "div.post h3.username", then you have to create a list with all the usernames (similar to the one you want to get rid of)  but more information is needed regarding how those names are contained in that element if you want more help with that.

As for using @ to retrieve usernames, depends on what you want. For example, if you insist that a new box must appear containing suggested usernames next to the written text, then it's not possible with textareas. This is because there is no cross-browser solution to localize the coordinates of where you're writing. Instead of a textarea, you have to use a div with a contenteditable attribute. However, if you're willing to have those usernames contained in another div below your textarea, then it's quite possible. If you want to describe what you are expecting, maybe I can provide some code.

You may want to prefer [this](http://imankulov.github.com/asuggest/) kind of autocompletion, though.

Comment: The list honestly can be right next to the textarea, that is fine honestly! Though what I am stating is say we are here in this text area. when I write @  I would want that div to appear on either left or right my choosing, with the list of users that have posted on that page. and get smaller when closer so like @Rober will come up with Robert Smith (P.S. the code I am using will not work with spaces in names only %20 is added I believe.)

Comment: Then hexist and Barmar's suggestion works quite well for you. Here a demo http://jsbin.com/usuwe/2.

Comment: Only problem to me is, Im a newb as you can tell. And Hexist I don't understand quite well. and Barmar I didn't understand what he was talking about nor how to go about it. Remember Im a newbie lol,.

Comment: No problem. This is the old Jquery UI Autocomplete documentation. Maybe you can find it easier to understand http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for the help Robert Smith! Greatly appreciated. I don't have it working yet of course but still loved the help. Ill get back to you with working or not. For now I'll accept your answer because you helped me with this more. Understanding is what I want, but a code more of the sorts could have help lol. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do to do fancy completion like searching from one list or another depending on content, you're going to want to do a custom search function. Instead of `source: availableTags` you'll be doing something like

```
source: function(request, response) { .... }
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for more details on how to write that function, but that'll give you the flexibilty you need to parse out @ symbols and that sort of thing.

Comment: I tried look at the link, and it gets me so confused LOL. thanks for answering so quickly btw. I'll try again to look at it

Answer (score 0):

Generating the list of tags dynamically is pretty easy. Instead of supplying an array for the `source:` option, supply a function that searches the DIV and returns all the tags that match.

Since your source function can look at what the user has typed, it can search the input for the word starting with `@` and use that when finding the completions.